# Google Maps API: How can I turn a `place_id` into geocoordinates?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps' predictive search in my app (the web based client side javascript version), [the API returns a list of locations without any location data.](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=AIzaSyC8-wZkpSNdGdlC4RUZO1-4Iv7zswKBNqo&location=53.345539%2C-6.269565&radius=10000&types=address&input=westmoreland%20stree%201)

A location returned by it may take this form,

```
  {
     "description" : "13 Westmoreland Street, Dublin, Ireland",
     "id" : "59e69e62d182fe1e60609e902483ba2868676e6d",
     "matched_substrings" : [
        {
           "length" : 22,
           "offset" : 0
        }
     ],
     "place_id" : "EicxMyBXZXN0bW9yZWxhbmQgU3RyZWV0LCBEdWJsaW4sIElyZWxhbmQ",
     "reference" : "CmRVAAAALZKJSrQW4Ht7bJX977JFDIXlyknbub1glCR9RpROHjUaGGP6ftkD7Z1wRC_9zF8ucPordpBlwf_vac8mQb66eRs3xyvi5GH2PWEhR8_m_towPFKnDJqHTqtjQhksbAD4EhDsuWADUOMHETJZk5i_K4fBGhRkpk15O3hzHysxpfky1sSznX9QXw",
     "terms" : [
        {
           "offset" : 0,
           "value" : "13 Westmoreland Street"
        },
        {
           "offset" : 24,
           "value" : "Dublin"
        },
        {
           "offset" : 32,
           "value" : "Ireland"
        }
     ],
     "types" : [ "route", "geocode" ]
  },
```

How I can covert this data into latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the documentation.

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#reverse-place-id

All I have to do  is make a request with the place ID and my API to this,

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?place_id=PLACE_ID&key=API_KEY
```

And I can extract the results.